# PIC32 connected via USB-Serial to Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, serial

Has anyone managed to get the PIC32MX695F512L microcontroller to connect via USB to the Raspberry Pi?  The PIC32 doesn't show up in lsusb or dmesg, however it will happily connect to my laptop with PuTTY.

It uses the standard USB-CDC driver that comes with Ubuntu Linux on my desktop machine, however it appears that Raspbian isn't able to communicate with the PIC32 by default. Searching the /dev folder doesn't show up anything "extra" when I plug it in, so I'm not convinced that Raspbian knows what to do with it.

If anyone knows how to get this working, I would greatly appreciate a few pointers.  Thanks! :D

Comment: Does `dmesg` show anything when you plug in the PIC? Raspbian is essentially Debian, so try googling for a debian solution might help.

Comment: lsusb -v should give you some hints

Answer (score 1):

If it's not showing up in dmesg or lsusb, it's a hardware problem rather than a linux driver problem. (Even if there's no Kerenl module for a device the physical connection should be made.) Is there any place on the PIC32 you can check the voltage? I suspect it's not getting enough current to power up correctly. Maybe try running it through a USB hub?